# Object Oriented programming in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, web

I know about Object Oriented programming and worked a lot in this field, but I'm completely new in programming web applications. (I worked some frameworks like Drupal, and CMSs like Joomla)

In a local application I know how to make new objects, how to using them and implementation.

**My Question:**

For a web application is it necessary to make Object Oriented models and if so what is the most important objects?

I will appreciate any idea ;)

Comment: OO means Object Oriented.and that is related to c#. Not a asp.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Web Application Scenarios you would be using OO to implement the parts of the framework you are working in, e.g. you be making Model, Views and Controllers for the MVC. Making entities for the Data layer etc. creating parts to be used for injection via dependency injection according to Inversion of control etc. .

So yes you be doing OOP as part of the much bigger things, because you OO has to fit within the system framework.

Answer (score 2):

**For a web application is it necessary to make Object Oriented models**
It is not compulsory, u seem to already know the power behind OOP so it is up to you
the typical web application in Asp.Net however involves classes and objects by default (check
code behind file of any aspx page, or the first line of its Html Source View)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5) and [Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application). With using `MVC` and `Entity Framework` all of your tables in the database become your Objects.And you can manipulate them however you like. And you can display your objects in your webpages with using View Models.